# Django - How to pass data (arguments?) with redirect function

Tags: python, django, redirect

I have a django view where a user uploads a large file. I scrape a ton of information from this file and hold it in memory. I don't want to save this information to the database because it takes too long and I don't need to save it. But I want to continue to use this data in the next view. How do I send along this data using redirect?

```
def view_one(request):
     if request.method == 'GET':
          return render(request, 'view_one.html')
     if request.method == 'POST':
          uploaded_file = request.FILES['my_file']
          info, data = scrape_my_file_for_info_and_data(uploaded_file)
          return redirect('path_to_view_two', info, data)

def view_two(request, info, data):
     do_stuff_with_info(info)
     do_stuff_with_data(data)
```

I keep getting errors that I am missing positional arguments 'info' and 'data'. I've tried doing:

```
return redirect('path_to_view_two', info=info, data=data)
return redirect(view_two(info, data))
```

But this doesn't work either. I can't find an example online of how to properly do this and I can't make heads or tails out of the django documentation. Seems there should be an easy way to do this, I just haven't landed on it.

Comment: isn't passing `**kwargs` or `context` to your view is what you are looking for?

Comment: No, this isn't kwargs or context. Or at least I don't think it is. I'm basically trying to pass this the way you would do it with a normal python function.

Comment: ok, did you checked `redirect()` docs? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect

Comment: Yes, they weren't very helpful. Unless they are telling me that I can't do what I'm trying to do?

Comment: but I believe that the second example is what you are looking for, redirect to a view with some arguments

Comment: @BaconSandwich And what exactly are `info` and `data`? If they are simply strings you can add them to your url pattern. Otherwise you simply cannot do this (redirecting with data does not work). Alternatives are storing things in the session (might require serialization) or simply using the database. Considering you say "_I don't want to save this information to the database because it takes too long_". I am sure you cannot add these into your url.

Answer (score 2):

According to [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect) you missed quotes in defining positional arguments

it should be like that:

```
return redirect('path_to_view_two', info='info', data='data')
```

Also you can consider saving data to user's session and retrieving on the redirected view - sessions [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/sessions/)

```
def view_one(request):
     data = scrape_my_file_for_info_and_data(uploaded_file)
     request.session['data'] = data

def view_two(request):
     data = request.session.get('data')
```

Comment: I will attempt to use the request.session. This might work. Thanks!